# Appache solr results multi sites search sorting based on specific feild

Tags: search

i have four sites and use appache solr module to execute search indexing in these four sites ,
all is ok with me , but the results sort not as i want

i want to sort by fields ......for ex:- get all result that have [field 1] first , then get all results that have [ field 2] ....

in my case , i have some results from [ field 1] then [ field 2] then [field 1] , ....
for note (my field type is taxonomy term and all contents in all four sites are the same )

Thanks

Comment: i used all available modules and edited in Bias , but still the sorting not as i want , i think there is specific case for taxonomy terms

Answer (score 0):

A **quick Solution** may be to use [Apache Solr Sort](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr_sort) Module.

> Per environment setting of grouping per content type/taxonomy/field
>   value/... Allow for a custom amount of items per group (global)

**But the best way is to setup a Apache Solr View :**

[Search API](http://drupal.org/project/search_api), has a [Solr integration module](http://drupal.org/project/search_api_solr), which will allow you to setup a View with exposed filters and full text search. With the flexibility of Views, you should be able to setup the view to allow the users to sort as they wish.